# Compute the standard basis of a pullback form dual to a different basis.

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider the basis $B = \{b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}\}$ of $\mathbb{R}^{3}$, where $b_{1} = (1, 0, 1)$,$b_{2} = (1, 1, 0)$, $b_{3} = (0, 2, 1)$.

Let $\{\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \beta_{3}\}$ be the basis of $(\mathbb{R}^{3})^{*}$ dual to $\mathcal{B}$.

Compute $\beta_{i}(w)$ for each $i = 1, 2, 3$, where $w = (2, 3, 5)$.

I am so in the woods with this question and do not even know where to begin.

In the textbook I am using, I am given this definition:

Let $B = \{ e_{1} , ... , e_{n}\}$ be a basis for $V$. The basis $B^{*} = \{ \epsilon_{1} , ... , \epsilon_{n} \}$ for $V^{*}$, where $\epsilon_{i} : V \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ are linear transformations defined by their action on the basis vectors as:

$e_{i}(\epsilon_{j}) = 1$ if $i = j$

$e_{i}(\epsilon_{j}) = 0$ if $i \neq j$

Does this mean that $\{\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \beta_{3}\} = \{b_{1}, b_{2}, b_{3}\}$ because of the def above?

I think that once I know the values of $\{\beta_{1}, \beta_{2}, \beta_{3}\}$ I should just multiply $w$ by each $\beta$.

Thank you for any help and any hints.

Comment: You may find this helpful https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150526/finding-the-dual-basis?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

The $i$th element of the dual basis just outputs the $i$th coordinate of its input vector, respect to the given basis.

It's because if $v=\alpha_1b_1+\alpha_2b_2+\alpha_3b_3$, then
$$\beta_i(v)=\alpha_i$$
because $\beta_i(b_i)=1$ and $\beta_i(b_j)=0$ if $j\ne i$.

It means that for this exercise you only need to write up the given vector as the linear combination of the given basis.

Note also that $\beta_i$ can be represented by $n\times1$ matrices, i.e. *row vectors*, and the dual basis criterion translates to
$$\pmatrix{&\beta_1&\\ &\beta_2&\\ &\beta_3}\pmatrix{\\ b_1&b_2&b_3\\ &&}=I\,,$$
that is, the matrix with the dual basis elements in the rows is just the *inverse* of the transition matrix from the standard basis to the given basis.